# Name of file and its suffix

Tags: filesystems

Is suffix ( for example .jpg or ,txt ) a part of file name ?
for example I have this file : "picture.jpg", what is file name in this file ?
thanks

Comment: +1 just cause I didn't think -1 was deserverd here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### *Yes,these suffixes are the part of the file name,as they are the formats*

in which the files are saved on to your computer,From [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename_extension)

> Filename extensions can be considered a type of **metadata**. They are
>   commonly used to imply information about the way data might be stored
>   in the file. The exact definition, giving the criteria for deciding
>   what part of the file name is its extension, belongs to the rules of
>   the specific filesystem used; usually the extension is the substring
>   which follows the last occurrence, if any, of the dot character
>   (*example: txt is the extension of the filename readme.txt, and html
>   the extension of mysite.index.html*).

Answer (score 2):

Read about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename_extension

> A filename extension is a suffix to the name of a computer file applied to indicate the encoding convention (file format) of its contents.